# C++ Linked List: IndexOf of an object

Tags: c++, indexing, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to find an index of a given object in my linked list.
I want to return -1 is the object doesn't exist in my list.
Below is my code, please guide me.

```
int List::indexOf(const Object& o) const
{
    Node* tempNode = first;
    int count = 0;
    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        if (o.compare(tempNode->o) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    ++count;
    tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why are you implementing your own linked list? What's wrong with `std::list`?

Comment: Why are you implementing your own linear search? What's wrong with `std::find`?

Comment: Yes I am implementing my own linked list, so I get started with C++

Comment: why are you writing your own code? what's wrong with `github`? /sarcasm

Comment: I'd guess that the clue is in his username. Implementing a linked list in _any_ language is a classic way of learning the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not return from inside the loop?

```
Node* tempNode = first;
    int count = 0;
    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
       if (o.compare(tempNode->o) == 0)
       {
           //return the count when you found a match
           return count;
       }
       ++count;
       tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }
    //return -1 if no match is found
    return -1;
}
```

You could also store an auxiliary that tells you whether the node was found or not, but this approach is cleaner IMO.